# Animate repeatable text

Tags: animation, text-object

I want to animate text same way as shown in NFT below using blender. Is it possible?

https://rarible.com/token/0xd07dc4262bcdbf85190c01c996b4c06a461d2430:540065?tab=owners

[image]

Comment: of course, you need to use the location values of the Mapping and plug the Mapping into the Image Texture that has your text

Comment: @moonboots: That's a cheap solution. Have a look at my answer for real hardcore Blender users...!

Comment: I'm disapointed I thought there would be a bit of Python or some Geometry nodes  :/

Comment: @moonboots I didn't learn geonodes yet, but made Python solution for you.

Comment: Ok I'm happy then  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python script

[image]

Copy the name of the text curve:

[image]

And paste it inside quotes on line 4:

```
import bpy

frames_per_change = 5
curve = bpy.data.curves["Text"]


def my_listener_text_update(scene):
    if not scene.frame_current % frames_per_change:
        curve.body = curve.body[1:] + curve.body[0]
    

listeners = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post
for l in (l for l in listeners if l.__name__ == "my_listener_text_update"): 
    # this is here so you can change the script and run it again without having
    # multiple listeners stacking - make sure the function name is unique
    listeners.remove(l)
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_listener_text_update)
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks

Comment: I'm new to python so do I have to copy entire script or only certain lines from it?

Comment: @RamizDzhavadov copy entire script into a new Text datablock and run it. To see the text changing, just press **space** or whatever shortcut you use for playback https://i.imgur.com/GrNlCfq.gif

Comment: Thank you so much, best solution so far.

Comment: I'd say it's the worst solution, I added it for fun, but if it works for you...

Comment: Chris's solution was great but it was causing problems when rendering and reduced FPS when playing animation to 7 FPS.

With your solution it didn't require a lot of work and it doesn't put a lot of tension on the system so for me it worked great. Thank you again!

... should start learning python I think ...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady btw is there any way to make movement of the text a bit "smoother"?

Comment: @RamizDzhavadov Yes if it's a monospaced font: you can parent the text to an empty, and move the empty (either in the script or by adding a driver) in a pattern fitting the letter wrapping. Since the letter wrap happens at frame number divisible by `frames_per_change`, you want to set the empty's x to the modulo divided by `frames_per_change` multiplied by letter width, e.g. `#-(frame % 5)/5 * 0.1`

Answer (score 7):

@moonboots in images ... create a text as texture and animate X location in Mapping node.
The easiest way is to create driver, just type `#frame*0.01` into *Mapping node > Location > X.*

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice one!!!!!! :D If I would have written such a solution, i BET at least one person would have written: but then you cannot use modifiers and don't have the freedom to do all that good stuff you can do with meshes.....!!! :D

Comment: Lets do setup or render speed competition ... than you will discover what real freedom means :)

Comment: give me another half year of learning (i started Blender half year ago)....then we can do. I am still beginner ... :D but i am really curious how your render speed competition would look like ;)

Answer (score 6):

No real hardcore Blender user would EVER use this very cheap solution moonboots proposes (which of course works and is too easy to use here).

So the real hardcore Blender user always (!) uses meshes to do things.

So first let's create this mesh here by just moving some vertices of a circle around:

[image]

Then convert it to a curve.

[image]

Then add a text object with a very important text, add an array modifier and adapt the constant offset so that it fits and looks good. And also add a curve modifier with the curve as object you created before.

[image]

Then you get this:

[image]

Then keyframe the x value of the curve to get his:

[image]

To "cut out" just the front we use some math in the shader editor like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

and if you then add a wave modifier to that...you get a REALLY COOL animation...(nope, can't be done with shaders....except your name is Robin Betts)

[image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: What I got after using math nodes in shader editor is that some part of text retained material color and some parts just became black. 

https://imgur.com/a/qpaqm69

Comment: Then provide blend file - I will check it out

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=w1qQGl6V" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/w1qQGl6V/)

Comment: just adapt the threshold to your needs -> my origin point was another than yours. try this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDgvh.png -> just "play" around with the values so you see what happens.

Comment: Don’t forget to set blend mode to alpha blend in your material!

Comment: Where was your origin? I'm thinking if mine is completely off.

Comment: i give u my blend file.....just a minute

Comment: blend file added

Comment: I see now, thank you so much for such detailed answer.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Now there's other problem occured... When I render final animation text just goes one on another. Do you know what might cause the problem? https://imgur.com/a/HKFTqRB

Comment: In my file or did you change something?

Comment: I just adjusted the factors in less than and greater than. And instead of using only one text object and arraying it, I created two text objects.

Comment: Ok, upload your file - I‘ll check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127400/discussion-between-chris-and-ramiz-dzhavadov).