# Change Text During Animation

Tags: text-object

I'm creating a 2D animation and I want the text in my animation to change based on the frame. I've added a text object and I can't figure out how to get the value to change during animation. It keeps whatever the last value I entered was for the whole duration. For example: I want the letter A to appear 120 keyframes into the animation and at 168 keyframes I want the letter A to no longer be visible. At 170 keyframes I want the letter X to appear. Sorry if this is super simple, I'm new to Blender and couldn't find a video or post that explained this.

Comment: do you want the letters to gradually happen or it goes from 0 to 100%?

Comment: Out of the box, there isn't any easy way to animate the text inside a text object. You can however make several text objects that contain the elements you want to animate, and animate the object's visibility through time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 3 strategies:

1. As L0Lock suggests, create two text objects, **A** and **X**, make both invisible for renders by clicking on render visibility icon [image], go to frame 119, select **A**, hover of the render icon and press <kbd>`I`</kbd> to keyframe it, then go to the frame 120, click the render visibility icon to enable visibility and then again <kbd>`I`</kbd> keyframe it. Go to frame 167, again keyframe visibility, go to frame 168 and disable visibility and keyframe it. Likewise keyframe the **X** object to be invisible on frame 169 and visible on frame 170. Of course instead of showing/hiding the objects suddenly, you can use *Build* modifier, or animate location (slide in/out), scale (pop in/out) or alpha property of Principled BSDF shader (you would need separate materials for each object).
2. Run a [Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230179/60486) which modifies the text.
3. Use Geometry Nodes like so:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I really appreciate it!